# Manually connect to PostgreSQL with Ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql, dbd

Connecting to postgres with rails was no big deal.  rails -d postgresql app_name, setup the database.yml and voila.  I cannot, however, use postgres with just a little test script

I've tried installing the gems postgres, dbi & dbd-pg, pg, and ruby-pg, but with pg/ruby-pg and postgres it fails at the require for require 'postgres' or require 'pg'.  With require 'dbi' I get past the require, but it can't load the driver....so how is rails doing it with the same set of packages? In fact I removed all the afore mentioned and found I only needed the 'pg' gem for everything to work fine with rails.  Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you remembering to add a `require 'rubygems'` to your source, or invoke `ruby` with a `-rubygems` argument, or add `RUBYOPT=rubygems` to your environment? You [need to do one of those](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page70) to actually load the gem machinery that allows `require` to find your gems.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Coming from the land of Perl, I had no idea.  You saved me a lot of wasted time.